# VS Code - space before function parentheses

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to disable removing space before parentheses when editing a function in VS Code?

Lets say I have a function

```
function render () {
    // some code here
}
```

When I start editing it, VS Code removes the space before parentheses and transforms this code to:

```
function render() {
    // some code here
}
```

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out I had `"editor.formatOnType": true` setting enabled. This is what makes the editor auto-format the code when you type. Disabling it helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: In my case was `"editor.formatOnSave": true` setting enabled. (I was having the issue when I was saving the file).

Comment: this just disables autoformatting, It doesn't fix the formatting to format as exptected

Comment: Can we remove that checkmark from that answer? That's a horrible advice. This only solves his issue because he hasn't set "editor.formatOnSave": true (generally spoken he doesn't use the linter anymore now) Well, uninstalling the linter will solve linter issues ok, I give him that. I also agree that formatOnType is a bit much, if you save here and then the formatOnSave is good enough (at least my practice)

Answer (score 71):

1. In VS Code open File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Add to your JSON config:

`"javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true`

```js
function render () {
    // some code here
}
```

`"javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": false`

```js
function render() {
    // some code here
}
```

3. Now you can continue using your auto format option `"editor.formatOnType": true`

Comment: For typescript, you can use the setting `"typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": true`

Answer (score 68):

I had opposite problem with anonymous functions. We use prettier extension. Auto-correct inserts a space before parenthesis. And then prettier complains about it.

```
var anonfunc = function() {
    // Expected syntax. 
}

var autocorrected = function () {
    // Auto-correct inserts a space
}
```

There is similar code option, which solves my problem:

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": false
```

By default it is `true`. Took me some time, until I was tired correcting auto-correct.

Comment: For typescript, you can use the setting `"typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": false`

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i am looking for, took a while to realize there are different settings for `normal` and `anonymous` functions. Looks like for **normal** function, this is `false` by default, but for **anonymous**, I have to set explicitly in *settings.json*.

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue with VSCode removing spaces after a constructor and ESLint complaining because there wasn't a space.

- Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings
- Search for `constructor`
- Add a check next to `JavaScript › Format: Insert Space After Constructor`

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I'm on the VSCode team. As of VSCode 1.8, this formatting option is not supported out of the box, but we are tracking the feature: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15386, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12234

As a workaround, try the following:

- Install the [eslint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint): `ext install eslint`
- Add `"eslint.autoFixOnSave": true` to your workspace or user settings
- In the root of your project, create an `.eslintrc.json` with:

  ```
  {
      ...
      "rules": {
          ...
          "space-before-function-paren": "error"
      }
  }
  ```

  The eslint extension can create a starter `.eslintrc.json` for you with the `create .eslintrc.json` command.

This will automatically format functions to have a space after them when you save the file.

Comment: Thank you for telling about this great setting. This is very useful. Until VS Code's settings don't go against these eslint rules. This isn't a workaround for my issue, the editor still formats my functions when I edit them, then eslint highlights the errors and when I save the file everything is right back to normal. This is really annoying and weird.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I wanted the normal indenting/formatting behavior of VS Code, so I disabled the eslint warning:

In the .eslintrc.js file I typed inside the rules:

```
 'rules': {
    ....

    //disable rule of space before function parentheses 
    "space-before-function-paren": 0
  }
```

Comment: This is simple, and works. BTW this config might be in `package.json` too.

Answer (score 4):

Also adding to Yan's answer, you can just hit the `Command + ,` on Mac or `CTRL + ,` on your keyboard then, add the following lines in your `settings.json`

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis": false,
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions": false
```

The second entry also disables the space for anonymous functions, on format e.g

```js
var anon = function() {
   // do something..
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I didnt know about insertSpaceAfterFunctionKeywordForAnonymousFunctions, it was the one I had to change on typescript since it seemed to overwrite the insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis

Answer (score 3):

### Problem:

My issue was in `package.json`

My project was using `prettier@1.18.2` which did not have the `space after the function keyword` or `arrowParens: 'always'` as default configuration.

One of the maintainers upgraded prettier to version 2 `prettier@2.3.2`, which had these two as default config. These were among the breaking changes in prettier version 2.

[https://prettier.io/blog/2020/03/21/2.0.0.html#always-add-a-space-after-the-function-keyword-3903](https://prettier.io/blog/2020/03/21/2.0.0.html#always-add-a-space-after-the-function-keyword-3903httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull3903-by-j-f1httpsgithubcomj-f1-josephfrazierhttpsgithubcomjosephfrazier-sosukesuzukihttpsgithubcomsosukesuzuki-thorn0httpsgithubcomthorn0-7516httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull7516-by-bakkothttpsgithubcombakkot)

[https://prettier.io/blog/2020/03/21/2.0.0.html#change-default-value-for-arrowparens-to-always-7430](https://prettier.io/blog/2020/03/21/2.0.0.html#change-default-value-for-arrowparens-to-always-7430httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull7430-by-kachkaevhttpsgithubcomkachkaev)

### Solution:

`npm ci` - just installed the npm packages again.

`npm install` will also work. `npm ci` will install exact versions from package-lock.json, while `npm install` would install latest versions with minor changes.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences, and search for `insertSpaceBeforeFunctionParenthesis` in the search bar at top.

Now, select the checkbox which says: `JavaScript: Format: Insert Space Before Function Parenthesis`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to explicitly enable ESLint on my Vue.js project even though I had a .eslintrc.js file that should have been implementing:

```
extends: ['plugin:vue/exxential', '@vue/standard']
```

To do that I pressed CTRL+Shift+P and searched for "ESLint: Enable ESLint"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on project settings, it will vary a bit.

e.g. if you have `env.es5` set the problem may arise.
This is my setup (I use `eslint-config-google` additionally & TS, just omit TS lines if JS only)

```json
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "google"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"]
}
```

I did not set anything to VSCode settings about formatting rules but I'm using auto format on save, check:

```json
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },
  "[jsonc]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },
  "[typescript]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },

  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

So instead of proposed ideas like overrriding rules or bypass the whole formatting you simply have to make sure the linter knows what environment it's in and apply those rules.

Prettier isn't the issue here, but if you like to get a `.prettierrc` config I've just created a helper package here:

https://github.com/artiphishle/prettierrc